# Mule ESB Box Connector- Can't run flow provided by example project

Tags: mule

**Ok, I did a little more research and it seems that MuleSoft is only offering 3.5.0 for Cloudhub deployments, at this time. The next major on-premises release will be sometime in the spring. Here are the [3.5.0 release notes](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+3.5.0+Andes+Release+Notes) and a [blog post](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/climbing-mountains-faster/) explaining the different release plans for Cloudhub and on-premise. Thanks to Anton for pointing me in the right direction.**

I am attempting to get the sample box connector project project running.

I generated a new project with the default pom file and copied the Flow from here https://github.com/mulesoft/box-connector/blob/master/demo/src/main/app/box-connector-demo.xml

I added the box and object store dependencies to my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-objectstore</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-box</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

The box connector requires Mule 3.5 to run. I am running Mule Studio version 3.5.0, however I updated my runtime and the latest version seems to be 3.4.2 EE. **So which version does the connector refer to?** Studio I hope.

So there is a possibility that my runtime is not correct.

Here is the error I am getting. I am missing a dependency for the Oauth functionality in the box connector. Not sure why the box connector install instructions did not include a dependency for this. Where can I find

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/security/oauth/config/AbstractDevkitBasedDefinitionParser**
(org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)

I searched the Maven repository for this class and it is in this dependency

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-devkit-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0-bighorn</version>
  </dependency>
```

When I added this dependency, I received another error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.common.connection.exception.UnableToAcquireConnectionException
```

I added a couple more 3.5.0 dependencies and then received a NoSuchMethodFoundException, which leads me to believe I now have some versioning issues. So I feel like I am in sort of a rat hole now. I am hoping that I am using the wrong runtime with the wrong dependencies. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Mule runtime 3.5.0 in latest Mule Studio, select the CloudHub December runtime. The Mule version in your pom.xml will then "magically" become 3.5.0-cascade... I have to warn you, though, that the listen-events/get-events combination in the Box connector demo [might not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611100/mule-box-connector-invalid-key-type-message-payload-is-of-type-string/21616680).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will update my post with a few links and a conclusion.